# Is it possible to make an undead be healed by positive energy and harmed by negative energy?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, undead, damage-types

There is a feat called Tomb-Tainted Soul:

> You are healed by negative energy and harmed by positive energy as if you were an undead creature.

I was wondering if there was the opposite feature: a feat or some other feature that would allow an undead (a vampire especially) to be healed by positive energy and harmed by negative, like it was a regular living creature?

Comment: Possible duplicate with: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/83560/are-undead-ever-healed-by-positive-energy

Comment: @Phlyk Related but not the same. That question is about a positive-energy effect that—by itself—heals undead. This is about some ability/feat/etc. that an undead can have—by itself—to reverse the normal positive/negative energy effects. It's analoguous to the difference between “is there a device that can translate Spanish to English for me?” and “can I learn to speak Spanish?”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Sort of

The 3rd-level Clr spell ***spark of life*** [necro] (*Spell Compendium* 196-7) does all sorts of horrible things to an undead creature, making it vulnerable to many things normally affecting only the living like…

- critical damage, ability damage, nonlethal damage
- fatigue and exhaustion
- poison
- energy drain
- effects requiring a Fortitude saving throw

In addition to the affected undead creature needing to eat, breathe, and sleep for the spell's 1-round-per-caster-level duration, the spell says, "While it is under the effect of this spell, both negative energy (such as *inflict* spells) and positive energy (such as *cure* spells) heal damage to the undead creature, rather than damaging it" (196).

So, as a sort of a left-handed blessing, but this has its uses—especially for an undead creature that wishes to conceal its type.

Comment: This still only provides the 'healed by positive energy' requirement... Not familiar with a way to accomplish 'hurt by negative energy'

Comment: I think this might accomplish the same goal. That is, I can imagine a group of do-gooders testing for vampirism by casting *cure* spells on suspects. I struggle to imagine a similar group (maybe of *do-badders*?) testing for vampirism by first stabbing suspects then casting *inflict* spells on them!

Comment: @HeyICanChan - why stab first? just cast inflict and see if they *don't* take damage... Anyhow, not sure what the OP needed this for. What I love about this spell is its roleplay and narrative applications - consider a wizard keeping his deceased beloved wife 'alive' *without her knowledge*...

Comment: They stab first because they (like me) tend to overthink things. `:-)` Yeah, both this spell and the *Races of Eberron* spell *greater humanoid essence* enable all kinds of wacky plots.

Comment: @G0BLiN Same (or similar) spell is in Spell Compedium and it is Cleric 3, Druid 4 level. You could add it to improve answer.

Comment: @Momonga-sama - never had the Spell Compendium - please feel free to add that to the answer if you have access to it